# Is there way to identify connected div by clicking connection line ? connections js

Tags: jquery, connection

I'm using connections js to connect components in my web app. I want to delete connection line when I double click on that line. To do that I want to identify connected components. So please help me to fix this issue.

[jsfiddle link][1]

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/SL_Mahasona/3sv4t3es
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: Please provide code snippet

Comment: hi @ManishShukla, I have insert jsfiddel link. please use that link to view my code. thanks.

Comment: Hi @CarstenLøvboAndersen, I include my jsfiddel link into this question.

Comment: @UdaraSuranga Is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/3sv4t3es/1/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes, this is what i'm looking for. Also I want to get connected component id. Is there a way to get this ?? Thank you

Comment: @UdaraSuranga What `id` when i look at the connector, there is no id on it

Comment: @UdaraSuranga look now https://jsfiddle.net/3sv4t3es/4/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen wow.. this is exactly what i want.. thanks a lot my friend. Can you please your jsfidel as an answer. then I can give you some credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the following code to achieve the wanted results from Udara

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
  $('#draggable3').connections({
    to: '#draggable4',
    'class': 'demo'
  });
  $.repeat().add('connection').each($).connections('update').wait(0);
});
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
  $('#draggable3').connections({
    to: '#draggable4',
    'class': 'demo',
    'data-from': '#draggable3',
    'data-to': '#draggable4'
  });
  $.repeat().add('connection').each($).connections('update').wait(0);

  $(document).on("dblclick", ".demo",function() {
    var from = $(this).attr("data-from");
    var to = $(this).attr("data-to");
    alert("from: " + from + " - to: " + to)
    $(this).remove()
  })
});
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/3sv4t3es/4/)